# How to add a license to the user using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli, azure-cli2

Is it possible to add license to the user using Azure CLI?

I am also trying to find whether Azure CLI can be used as a replacement for AzureAD powershell module?

Comment: Azure Cli 2.0 is design for ARM mode. So, you could not use it to manage classic resource. But, Azure powershell can.For open issue related to Azure CLI you can browse - https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues

Comment: Azure CLI can do most things as PowerShell. What do you mean to add the license to the user using Azure CLI? Assign role for the user?

Comment: I have added a new user and trying to add Office 365 license to the user so that the complete office suite is available to that user.
If you go to Azure Portal  and edit the user then you will see License menu item in there.

Comment: It seems there is no CLI command can achieve that. All the CLI command for the user list in [`az ad user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/user?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles for the answer.

Comment: If it works t you, you can add the answer for others who are looking for a similar question.